# Apply some other tag to the 19 remaining untagged questions

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The current tag excerpt of [untagged](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is like so:

> This is a special tag that is designed to be used only by the system for questions that have had all of their other tags removed. Do not add this tag to existing questions, it is reserved for use by the system to identify posts with no valid tags.

Currently there are [19 untagged questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/untagged/info) onn Drupal.SE, that is: 19 questions with [untagged](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) as the only tag. Most (if not all) of these 19 questions have been explicitly retagged from some tag to the [untagged](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag, by moderators.

Some time ago (a few months?) there were around 100 of such untagged questions. Many of them I was able to cleanup via editing these questions and replacing the untagged tag with an applicable tag. The remaining 19 questions seem to be out-of-my-controle, hence this question ...

Comment: Each question needs to be evaluated separately, and tagged appropriately; retag requests are for: _requests to replace one tag with another existing tag_. We can't really do that in this situation

Comment: OK, I reworded my question ... and corrected the 25 to 19 (the reduced number since I first posted this question).

Answer (score 3):

I cleaned up some old, blatantly off-topic questions, and edited [untagged](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) out of the other questions. Now there aren't any questions using it.